# Problema combobox con ajax y php permanentemente actualizado

Tags: ajax, combobox

Buenas tengo un problema
Estoy cantando un combobox con una consulta php por medio de ajax
Me trae perfecto los datos pero el problema lo tengo cuando otro usuario carga datos en la tabla que estoy viendo en el combobox, en este no se me agrega el nuevo registro sin que actualice la pagina
Estoy casi seguro que es un tema de llamar a la funcion permanentemente pero no me estoy dando cuenta de donde esta el problema
Dejo el codigo por si alguien me puede dar una mano
Muchas gracias

Archivo function.js

```
function cargar_categorias() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_categorias.php",
    success: function (a) {
      $("#categoria").html(a);
    },
  });
  return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  cargar_categorias();
});
```

archivo ajax_categorias.php

```
<div class="input-group-text">CAT</div>
<select class="form-select" name="a" id="a">
    <?php
    $sql_categorias = "SELECT * FROM art_categorias order by categoria asc";
    if ($res_categorias = mysqli_query($link, $sql_categorias)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res_categorias) > 0) {
            while ($row_categorias = mysqli_fetch_array($res_categorias)) {
                echo "<option value=" . $row_categorias['id'] . ">" . utf8_encode($row_categorias['categoria']) . "</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Archivo donde se muestra la consulta ver.html

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
   <div class="input-group" id="categoria" onfocus="cargar_categorias()"></div>
</div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Cuando usas `$(document).ready(function () {`, llamas eso UNA vez, al terminar de cargar la página. Necesitas recargar la tabla cada N tiempo? Necesitas algo que se ejecute regularmente como setInterval

Comment: si el problema es que si la cargo cada x segundos por ejemplo, como varias personas están usando al mismo tiempo el sistema, es como que si lo tienen abierto se les cierra o les parpadea. Por eso lo que buscaba era que constantemente este actualizado el contenido. Si alguien caga un nuevo registro, el mismo aparezca sin que se note en el combobox. No se si es posible de hacer realmente lo que busco

Comment: Y si desde la base de datos mandas un evento cada 1 segundo para que verifique ello y te despreocupas por al parte del front? A menos que tengas limitaciones en la BD, no lo vería ineficiente.

Comment: La verdad que no se como hacer eso que planteas. Voy a investigar sobre el tema. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta cambiando el `onfocus` por `onclick`, o si tienes una función previa puedes ejecutar la función `cargar_categorias()` desde allí.